# Chek if an element is x times in some array of a 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

**I want something that returns True if 0 appears x times in some array of a 2D array withou using for loop**

```
a= [[1,2,0,4],[1,0,0,4],[0,2,3,4]]
b= [[1,2,0,4],[1,0,3,4],[0,2,3,4]]
x= 2
```

for a the function will return True and for b the function will return False
Or at least i need to find the max number of zeroes, for a it is 2 and for b it is 1
I dont want to use for loop because i have arrays with million elements and i have to do it many times

Comment: what do you mean without using for loop? any other numpy or similar fancy function is going to use for loop in some way or another.

Comment: I mean without using it like for i in a , because in that way it gonna take hours

Comment: In my point of view, you have to search it linear way and worst case complexity will always will be n*m (size of 2D array).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
zeros = arr.shape[1] - np.count_nonzero(arr, axis = 1)
np.any(zeros >= x)
```

Works only if the arrays are non-jagged.

UPDATE:
Timing this code with `%timeit` in Jupyter for `arr` of shape `(10000, 100)`, we get:

```
2.27 ms ± 21.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As per the comments, since the code is supposed to run on these ~1M elements for  ~100K times, in my opinion, a good bet is to use [`cupy`](https://cupy.chainer.org/) to achieve this. Since `cupy` requires CUDA, if you do not wish to install it locally, you can use it on *Google Colab* (you have to install it there, though). On Google Colab, one run takes on an average with `cupy`:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 µs per loop
```

That's more than a 10 times improvement. The code is same (since `cupy` is supposed to be a *drop-in replacement* for `numpy`):

```
import cupy as cp
arr = cp.random.choice(cp.arange(-3, 3), size = (10000, 100))
zrs = cp.count_nonzero(x, axis = 1); cp.any(zrs >= x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried, but its too slow, do you have a faster way?

Comment: The array has like 1 million elements

Comment: And the problem is that i have to execute it more than 100000 times

Comment: With an array of size (10000, 100) (= 1 mn elements) the code takes ~2.5ms to run. How much faster do you want to go?

Comment: The array has 1 million arrays inside and in every array there are 14 integers

Comment: Check the edited post and the sample array. Barring the different _types_ of integers, isn't this what you ask for?

Comment: Im going to test it tomorrow! Thank you

Comment: The shape of my array is ~(1000000, 14)

Comment: With cupy it is giving me 0,001 seconds, 10 ms, is too much

Comment: I can pass you the whole function if you want

Comment: Look, if you're planning to make such an operation (not a simple one like addition of elements) on 14M elements 100K times, it should take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy library for that. just import numpy and do like this.

```
import numpy as np
np.count_nonzero([[0,1,7,0,0],[3,0,0,2,19]], axis=1)
```

output is,

```
array([2, 3])
```

Now if you know your shape of axis it's easy to find.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried, but its too slow, do you have a faster way?

Comment: As you said millions of elements and you need to do it more than 100000 times, it will definitely take time. Sorry I don't know any better way.